# Oracle 11 migration linux - windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Oracle 11.2.0.4, base 300 Gb, CentOs.
Need migration to new server on Windows. Downtime 4 hours allowed.

I use rman to backup base and logs and control file.

On new server install same version base, restore spfile and control file.
Now don't how change path to tablespace (linux \app.., Windows D:..)
Need create new control file or another way?

Comment: try asking here instead - https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Found this link with steps that might work, but there may be some limitations. https://software.databasedevelop.com/article/12248020/Restore+Linux+rman+backup+in+windows